# MongoDB Now > Interval Like SQL

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I used mysql before mongodb and I must convert the following sql query to mongo:

```
WHERE NOW() > (Field + INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

I just find a way to check if a date is between to dates but this isn't a solution for me.

Sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54cd524be811410c1048a9ef"),
    "UserID" : 0,
    "root" : {
        "files" : [ 
            {
                "FileID" : 1,
                "UploadStatus" : "Unfinished",
                "FileName" : "",
                "FileSize" : 3.2,
                "FileKey" : "",
                "StartUploadRequest" : "2015-01-11 16:43:11",
                "ServerID" : 0,
                "Path" : [                         
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261506/translation-of-sql-query-to-mongo-languague/28261755#28261755

Comment: maybe this is helpful, but i cant imaging how i can processing my query with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really need your sample mongo document but I assumed you have something like this in your collection:

```
{
    _id = "item0",
    Field : ISODate("2014-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
}
```

Then:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[    
    { $project : { 'comp' : { $add : ['$Field', (3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000)] }, Field : 1 } },
    { $match : { 'comp' : { $lt : new Date()} } },
]).result
```

I above query `new Date()` will give us `Now` and `(3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000)` will produce 3 day offset in milliseconds.

**Update:**

Based on your sample denouement the query should be:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[    
    { $unwind : '$root.files'}, 
    { $project : { 'comp' : { $add : ['$root.files.StartUploadRequest', (3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000)] }, 'root.files': 1 } },
    { $match : { 'comp' : { $lt : new Date()} } },
]).result
```

Comment: db.user_folders.aggregate(
[    
    { $project : { 'comp' : { $add : ['$StartUploadRequest', (3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000)] }, 'StartUploadRequest' : 1 } },
    { $match : { 'comp' : { $lt : new Date()} } },
]).result but it doesnt work. ok is 1 but result length = 0. i post my structur in the answers

Comment: there are some problems, first of all your StartUploadRequest is string, not IsoDate()

Comment: @Hendrik, you have to delete your answer, I updated your question with sample document, And you should not to post the edits or samples as answer

Comment: Thanks man. u are the best. it works :)) I delete it. Sorry next time i dont make the same mistakes

Comment: Would you mark as answer the solution, there is a little tick top left of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply adjust now by 3 days and then query against that:

```
db.collection.find({root.files.StartUploadRequest:
     {$lt : new Date(new Date()-(3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000))}})
```

Comment: You are right, I don't know why I came with that complicated solution. +1